# Exportar e Importar Tabela Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, banco-de-dados, wordpress, tabela-banco-de-dados

Tenho um plugin Wordpress, que pode ser usado em vários blogs com a mesma configuração.

Tenho duas tabelas nele: wp_tabela_um e wp_tabela_2

Como posso criar um botão para exportar essas tabelas e um campo para importar no caso de uma nova instalação.

Comment: Sua pergunta esta muito vaga, de mais detalhes do que precisa e do que já tem.

Comment: você quer exportar apenas as tabelas ou as tebelas e os registros?

Comment: Andrei, preciso exportar os registros, porque quando o usuário for importar a tabela já estará criada no wordpress dele.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apesar da pergunta um pouco vaga e fez minha resposta ficar grande criei uma solução.

Como você sabe qual é a tabela os campos e seus atributos, faremos primeiro a seleção dos registros, criaremos os arquivos e depois inserimos no banco de dados. Vou criar apenas o exemplo com `wp_tabela_um` depois é só replicar para demais tabelas.

Crie um botão `<a href="gerarArquivo.php">criar arquivos</a>` simples para gerar os arquivos.

**gerarArquivo.php**

```
// selecionamos os registros

    $quer_wp_tabela_um = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM wp_tabela_um");

    // cria o arquivo wp_tabela_um

    while($registro = mysqli_fetch_array($quer_wp_tabela_um)){

        // abaixo criamos o arquivo se ele não existir COM DATA
        // o a+ indica que o arquivo é para escrita e leitura

        $arquivo = fopen("arquivos/wp_tabela_um".date("d-m-Y").".txt", "a+");

        // aqui você coloca os campos dos registros

        $campo1 = $registro['id'];
        $campo2 = $registro['nome'];
        $campo3 = $registro['email'];
        $campo4 = $registro['telefone'];

        // string completa com delimitador (;) e quebra de linha \n
        $string = $campo1.";".$campo2.";".$campo3.";".$campo4."\n";

        if ($arquivo) {

            // aqui escreve linha por linha no arquivo
            fwrite($arquivo, $string);

        }

        fclose($arquivo);

    }
```

Agora esses arquivos se encontram no diretório `arquivo` do seu site.

Com esses arquivos fazemos o envio para determinado banco de dados de uma vez só com um formulário de envio:

**formularioDeEnvio.php**

```
<form action="importarArquivos.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <input type="file" name="arquivo"/>
    <input type="submit"/> 

</form>
```

**importarArquivos.php**

```
$arquivos = $_FILES['arquivo'];

    // caminho com o diretório do arquivo
    $file = "arquivos/".$arquivos['name'];

    // salve o arquivo no diretório
    move_uploaded_file($arquivo['tmp_name'], $file);

    // abre o arquivo apenas para leitura
    $arquivo = fopen($file, 'r');

    // vamos ler o arquivo linha por linha e registra-lo

    while(!feof($arquivo)){

        //pega a linha atual
        $linha = fgets($arquivo);

        $registro =  explode(";" , $linha);

        $id = $registro[0];
        $nome = $registro[1];
        $email = $registro[2];
        $telefone = $registro[3];

        //insere o registro
        mysqli_query($mysqli, "INSERT INTO wp_tabela_um (id, nome, email, telefone) VALUES ($id, $nome, $email, $telefone)");

    }
```

Isso é só um exemplo! Pois existem varias formas de fazer